# Add Purchase Note Meta on Product Create - WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, hook-woocommerce

Can anyone help me with the below code? I am trying to add a custom purchase note to a newly created product only if the Product Name contains the string "Fiat".

```
add_action( 'transition_post_status', 'bbloomer_add_custom_meta_on_publish_product', 9999, 3 );

function bbloomer_add_custom_meta_on_publish_product( $new_status, $old_status, $post ) {

$product = wc_get_product( id );
$prod_name = $product->get_title();
$string_to_find = 'Fiat';

if ( 'product' === $post->post_type && 'publish' === $new_status && 'publish' !== $old_status && strpos( strtolower($product_name), $string_to_find ) === true ) {
  update_post_meta( $post->ID, '_purchase_note', 'This is my Fiat text' );
}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
add_action('woocommerce_before_product_object_save', 'save_product_before_action', 10, 2);

function save_product_before_action($product, $data_store) {


    if ($product->get_id()) {

        $prod_name = $product->get_name();
        $string_to_find = 'Fiat';

        if (strpos($prod_name, $string_to_find) !== false) {
            $product->set_purchase_note('This is my Fiat text');
        }
    }
}
```